# Sharing Wireless Internet connection

Tags: internet-connection, connection-sharing

I Have a two desktop computers, where one has an usb wireless adapter and the other does not. I was wondering that is there some kind of software, where I can connect the two computers with ethernet cable, and allowing the other desktop to have internet connection. Is there some kind of software that allows this to work?

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: The one that has the wifi adapter is Windows 7.  The other I'm planning to put a linux distro on it.

Answer (score 1):

- Have the Windows 7 computer with the WIFI adapter receive its internet access via wireless.
- Have your Linux computer connect to your Windows 7 computer via an ethernet cable.
- Enable Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) on the Windows 7  computer.
- No configuration needed on the Linux box - you should be good to go!

> How to enable ICS in Windows:
>
> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing